# How to make wrapped div expand to full width

Tags: html, css

I have the following UI:

[image]

When I make the window thinner, the div's wrap to accommodate, like so:

[image]

What I'd like see happen is when it does wrap, the div's expand to 100% width of space available.

The actual 'div.row's are 100% width in browser, so they are correct, but 'div.col-md-6's remain at the min-width setting, so it's them that I'm focusing on.

**Question:** How to make wrapped div's expand to 100% width?

This is the HTML, just using bootstrap css:

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Report Parameters</legend>
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%; max-width: none;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0; min-width: 554px;">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; height: 470px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span class="font-bold font-medium">Timelapse Templates</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <span>Please select a template:</span>
              <div class="feed-activity-list" style="display: block;">
                <div id="GridTLTemplates"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0; min-width: 554px;">
          <div class="tlTemplateDetail" style="height: 494px;">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="font-bold  font-medium">Timelapse Template Detail</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default" style="">
              <div class="feed-activity-list">
                <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Template Name:</label>
                <div style="padding: 5px;">
                  <input type="text" id="tbxTemplateName" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default" style="">
              <div class="feed-activity-list">
                <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Based-on Saved Query:</label>
                <div style="padding: 5px;">
                  <div id="basedOnQueryContainer">
                    <div class="e-tab-header">
                      <div>My Queries </div>
                      <div>Public Queries </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="e-content">
                      <div>
                        <div id='GridMyQueries'></div>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <div id='GridPublicQueries'></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0; min-width: 554px;">
          <div class="container" style="width: 100%; max-width: none; padding: 0;">
            <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
              <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0; min-width: 277px; width: 50%">
                <div class="tlTemplateDetail">
                  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0;">
                    <div class="feed-activity-list" style="height: 270px;">
                      <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Select an interval:</label>
                      <div style="padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
                        <div style="text-align: left;">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rbnIntervalHour" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rbnIntervalDay" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rbnIntervalWeek" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rbnIntervalMonth" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="radio" id="rbnIntervalYear" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                          <span style="padding-top: 30px;">Each interval will create a frame in the <span style="white-space: pre">time-lapse</span> map.</span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
                          <span style="margin-top: 25px;">Week = Sunday to Saturday</span>
                          <br />
                          <span>Month = Calendar month</span>
                          <br />
                          <span>Year = Calendar year</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0; min-width: 277px; width: 50%">
                <div class="tlTemplateDetail">
                  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0;">
                    <div class="feed-activity-list" style="height: 270px;">
                      <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Select date period:</label><br />
                      <div style="padding: 5px;">
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='radio' id='rbnDatePeriodFixed' />
                              <div id="DatePeriodDetailFixed" style="display: none; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; width: 100%; margin: 2px;">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <input id='dpFixedDateStart' type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <input id='dpFixedDateEnd' type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <span>Dates will be adjusted to fit the selected interval</span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='radio' id='rbnDatePeriodCumulative' />
                              <div id="DatePeriodDetailCumulative" style="display: none; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; width: 100%; margin: 2px;">
                                Blah blah blah
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type='radio' id='rbnDatePeriodRolling' />
                              <div id="DatePeriodDetailRolling" style="display: none; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; width: 100%; margin: 2px;">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <label>Number of Intervals:</label>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <input id="nbxRollingDate" type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 0; min-width: 554px;">
          <div class="container" style="width: 100%; max-width: none">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0; min-width: 277px; width: 50%">
                <div class="tlTemplateDetail ">
                  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0;">
                    <div class="feed-activity-list" style="height: 270px;">
                      <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Select a geographic grouping:</label><br />
                      <div style="padding: 5px;">
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="radio" id="rbnGeoGroupingState" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="radio" id="rbnGeoGroupingCounty" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="radio" id="rbnGeoGroupingZipCode3" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0; min-width: 277px; width: 50%">
                <div class="tlTemplateDetail ">
                  <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:0;">
                    <div class="feed-activity-list" style="height: 270px;">
                      <label class="control-label nowrap sectionTitle">Map Options:</label>
                      <div style="padding: 5px;">
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="tlMapOptionsAccumCounts" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="tlMapOptionsShowCounts" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <div style="padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9; border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; width: 100%; margin: 2px;">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <label style="white-space: normal;">Seconds to display each map frame:</label>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <input id="nbxFrameRate" type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `media query`. Go to Inspect Element and check on exactly which screen size does the change occur.

Say for example, if it was at 500px, then do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  #div_name {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

So, what that does is when anything below 500px or another way to think, when something goes below 500px, that `#div_name` becomes 100% width.

Try and see if this works for you.

Comment: Replace that `#div_name` to an actual ID of that particular section. Just try out with 1 first, once it works, you can implement this for all. Since you are using bootstrap, don't target the global variables such as `col-md-6` and stuffs like that as even your nested `col-md-6` will get affected. Include that section it is in, most probably in a div and it should work fine!

Comment: Awesome thank you Gosi, I have never played around with @media before so did some research, removed globals and got it sorted, excellent answer.

Comment: Np @Hank, really glad it helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put classes for small devices also (md is for medium devices and sm is for small devices)
Wherever you want full div on small screen please add class col-sm-12